# Ayuda con Mongodb + PHP + hightcharts

Tags: php, mongodb, highcharts

Estimados, no me funciona el siguiente código no se cual es la parte que estoy haciendo mal este es el código:

Queria poder ver un Gráfico de lineas del api highcharts

```
<?php
$dbname = 'db';

$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->$dbname;

$collection = $db->prueba3;
$results = $collection->find();
    $series = array('first_test'=>[], 'second_test'=>[], 'third_test'=>[]);
    $xAxis = array();
        foreach ($results as $result)
        {
            foreach($series as $key => $values)
                {
                    $series[$key][] = $result[$key];
                }
                        $xAxis[] = $result['date'];
        }


?> 
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script>
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
            xAxis:  {
                categories: [<?php echo json_encode($xAxis); ?> ]                   
                    },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                    },  
                series: [{
                            name:'<?php echo $key ?>',
                            data:[
                                <?php 
                                    foreach($series as $key => $dataPoints)
                                    {
                                ?>
                                    [<?php echo json_encode($dataPoints) ?>],
                                <?php 
                                    } 
                                ?>
                                ]
                        }]
               });
         });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

y mi colección tiene este formato:

```
 { 
    "_id" : NumberInt(1), 
    "date" : "2015-07-19", 
    "name" : "StressTest", 
    "first_test" : 4279.558451, 
    "second_test" : 4296.838515, 
    "third_test" : 825.446594, 
    "min" : 2.827739, 
    "max" : 6071.036922, 
    "station" : "Alpha1"
}
```

Al visualizar el código fuente en browser veo esto

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>


 <script>
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
            xAxis:  {
                categories: [(["2015-07-19","2015-07-20","2015-07-22"]) ]                   
                    },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                    },  
                series: [{
                            name:'third_test',
                            data:[
                                                                    [([4279.558451,5279.558451,6279.558451])],
                                                                    [([4296.838515,5296.838515,6296.838515])],
                                                                    [([825.446594,925.446594,1025.446594])],
                                                                ]
                        }]
               });
         });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Este es el grafico que me sale:

[image: Resultado del codigo]

Comment: Puedes especificar un poco más exacto que lo que es que no funciona? Que esultado esperas, que resultado recibes, existen errores en salida o logs?

Comment: estimado, lo que pretendo hacer con este código es poder ver un grafico de lineas estoy utilizando la api de highcharts... de antemano gracias @StefanNolde

Comment: al mirar el código html de tu salida en el browser, comprobaste si se están poblando los parámetros de xAxis?

Comment: @amenadiel no sabría como hacer lo que me preguntas...

Comment: En el browser, CTRL+U te muestra el código que se está generando. Es el javascript que mostraste más lo que escriba PHP en donde lo hayas llamado. Con eso podrás ver qué se le está pasando realmente a highcharts

Comment: @amenadiel este seria el resultado de lo que me preguntaste

Comment: Pero ese no es el código fuente. Tienes que usar CTRL+U (aunque estoy viendo que en Safari se hace con Cmd-Option-V)

Comment: ahora ví que modificaste tu pregunta. ¿Esos valores son antes o después de aplicar el código que te puse?

Comment: eso es antes de lo que me enviaste

Answer (score 0):

Creo que ya se cual es el problema. Le estás pasando la salida de `json_encode` (un string) a los parámetros de Highcharts que esperan un objeto.

Lo siguiente podría funcionar:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
            xAxis:  {
                categories: [JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($xAxis); ?>) ]                   
                    },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                    },  
                series: [{
                            name:'<?php echo $key ?>',
                            data:[
                                <?php 
                                    foreach($series as $key => $dataPoints)
                                    {
                                ?>
                                    [JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($dataPoints); ?>)],
                                <?php 
                                    } 
                                ?>
                                ]
                        }]
               });
         });
</script>
```

Comment: estimado @amenadiel , muchas gracias pero copie el script como esta y me error ahi coloque la imagen que me da con el código que elabore...

Comment: De nuevo, puedes hacer CTRL+U en el browser y ver qué configuración le estás pasando a Highcharts?